# Used bootstrap framework website looks good when resized but not on iphone

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap framework and a template from a book to finally make the master page the way I want.

When I use google chrome, or IE, and I resize the browsers, the page is resized and the menu is converted to a vertical menu.

However, I just tried on the iphone and it shows "like" a big browser, instead of showing the vertical menu.

I wish I could paste the code but the bootstrap code is way too long to copy here.

I will show my website:
https://levalencia-public.sharepoint.com/

And I will paste the html of my masterpage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--SPG:

This HTML file has been associated with a SharePoint Master Page (.master file) carrying the same name.  While the files remain associated, you will not be allowed to edit the .master file, and any rename, move, or deletion operations will be reciprocated.

To build the master page directly from this HTML file, simply edit the page as you normally would.  Use the Snippet Generator at https://levalencia-public.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/ComponentHome.aspx?Url=https%3A%2F%2Flevalencia%2Dpublic%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2F%5Fcatalogs%2Fmasterpage%2Flv%2Emaster to create and customize useful SharePoint entities, then copy and paste them as HTML snippets into your HTML code.   All updates to this file will automatically sync to the associated Master Page.

-->
<!DOCTYPE html[]>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
        <!--CS: Start Page Head Contents Snippet-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <!--SID:00 -->
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server">-->
            <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">-->
                <!--MS:<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server">-->
                <!--ME:</SharePoint:ProjectProperty>-->
            <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:PageTitle>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:StartScript runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:StartScript>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="15">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssLink>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:CacheManifestLink runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:CacheManifestLink>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:PageRenderMode runat="server" RenderModeType="Standard">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:PageRenderMode>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="menu.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="callout.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sharing.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="suitelinks.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:CustomJSUrl>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" Container="false" runat="server">-->
            <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">-->
            <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
            <!--MS:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true">-->
            <!--ME:</SharePoint:DelegateControl>-->
            <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">-->
            <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPWebPartManager" runat="server">-->
            <!--MS:<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server">-->
            <!--ME:</WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager>-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
        <!--CE: End Page Head Contents Snippet-->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!--DC:Specter Group - Blog Bootstrap Version-->
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/superfish.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/isotope.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elements.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />

        <!-- Modernizr enables HTML5 elements &#38; feature detects for optimal performance.
        Include html5shiv 3.6. Our version is a custom build.
       Create your own custom Modernizr build: www.modernizr.com/download/ -->
        <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.custom.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <!--Grab Microsofts CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
        <!--place in head in case need to access jquery inline in SP page layout-->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <script>//<![CDATA[window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">//<![CDATA[<\/script>')//]]>
        </script>
        <!--used to help make old scripts work with jquery 1.9-->
        <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <!--js libraries-->
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <script src="js/hoverIntent.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <script src="js/superfish-1.4.8/superfish.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <script src="js/superfish-1.4.8/supersubs.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.tweet.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.tabs.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <script src="js/poshytip-1.1/jquery.poshytip.min.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <!--custom scripts-->
        <script src="js/jquery-custom.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
        </script>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:HtmlDesignFromMaster msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignFromMaster>
<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">https://levalencia-public.sharepoint.com/_catalogs/masterpage/lv.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101000F1C8B9E0EB4BE489F09807B2C53288F0054AD6EF48B9F7B45A142F8173F171BD10003D357F861E29844953D5CAA1D4D8A3A00A9586E0672297E4794AD6E170F2BEB51</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--CS: Start Ribbon Snippet-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="wssucw" TagName="Welcome" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/Welcome.ascx"%>-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" HideFromSearchCrawler="true" EmitDiv="true">-->
            <div id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
                <a id="linkTurnOnAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(true);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOffAcc').focus();return false;">
                    <!--MS:<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="&lt;%$Resources:wss,master_turnonaccessibility%&gt;" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode">-->
                    <!--ME:</SharePoint:EncodedLiteral>-->
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="TurnOffAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
                <a id="linkTurnOffAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(false);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOnAcc').focus();return false;">
                    <!--MS:<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="&lt;%$Resources:wss,master_turnoffaccessibility%&gt;" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode">-->
                    <!--ME:</SharePoint:EncodedLiteral>-->
                </a>
            </div>
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
        <div id="ms-designer-ribbon">
            <!--SID:02 {Ribbon}-->
            <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify) --><div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="background:rgb(0, 114, 198); color:white; width:100%; padding:8px; height:64px; overflow:hidden;">The SharePoint ribbon will be here when your file is either previewed on or applied to your site.</div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW -->
        </div>
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AnonymousUsersOnly">-->
            <!--MS:<wssucw:Welcome runat="server" EnableViewState="false">-->
            <!--ME:</wssucw:Welcome>-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
        <!--CE: End Ribbon Snippet-->
        <div id="s4-workspace">
            <div id="s4-bodyContainer">
                <!-- HEADER -->
                <header>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span8">
                                <div id="logo">
                                    <!--logo snippet-->
                                    <div data-name="SiteLogo"><!--CS: Start Site Logo Snippet--><!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>--><!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta BlockElement="true" runat="server">--><!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW--><!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink CssClass="ms-siteicon-a" runat="server" ID="x8b0737e1232643da88f7b4721567d1e8">--><!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW--><!--MS:<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" ID="x596f04b7f65943cb9ad23b9fd9ac5744" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png" runat="server">--><!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><img id="ctl00_x596f04b7f65943cb9ad23b9fd9ac5744" class="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" Src="/SiteAssets/logosharepointazul.PNG" alt="Luis Valencia - Sharepoint Architect" /><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW--><!--ME:</SharePoint:SiteLogoImage>--><!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW--><!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink>--><!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW--><!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>--><!--CE: End Site Logo Snippet-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tagline">
                                    <h2>
                                        <span>Luis
                                        </span>
Valencia                                    </h2>
                                    <h2>
                                        <span>Sharepoint
                                        </span>
Architect                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="social cf">
                                <ul class="cf">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Sharepoint-Architects-Blog/259727274196140" target="_blank">
                                            <img src="img/social/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://twitter.com/levalencia" target="_blank">
                                            <img src="img/social/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter" />
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://plus.google.com/115487123900000828421/posts" target="_blank">
                                            <img src="img/social/Google+.png" alt="Google+" />
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=55314636&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile" target="_blank">
                                            <img src="img/social/LinkedIn.png" alt="Linked In" />
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <img src="img/social/RSS.png" alt="Blog" />
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <a class="social-toggle" title="Follow Us">Toggle
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <!-- ENDS HEADER -->
                <!-- nav -->
    <!-- nav -->
    <nav id="topnav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <div class="container">
                                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="nav nav-collapse collapse">
                                    <!--nav snippet-->
                                    <ul class="root">
                                        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="communities.html">ARTICLES</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <!--end nav snippet-->
                                </div> <!--end class nav-->
                            </div> <!--end container-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--end span 12-->
            </div> <!--end row-->
        </div> <!--end fluid container-->
    </nav>
    <!-- ends nav -->              


                <!-- MAIN -->
                <div role="main" id="main">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <!--main content placerholder, use the following html as sample content for content placeholder-->
                        <div class="row-fluid">

                                        <div data-name="ContentPlaceHolderMain">
                    <!--CS: Start PlaceHolderMain Snippet-->
                    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                    <!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain" IsMainContent="true" runat="server">-->
                        <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">-->
                            <div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="border:medium black solid; background:yellow; color:black; margin:20px; padding:10px;">
            This div, which you should delete, represents the content area that your Page Layouts and pages will fill. Design your Master Page around this content placeholder.

                            </div>
                        <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
                    <!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
                    <!--CE: End PlaceHolderMain Snippet-->
                </div>


                        </div>
                        <!--end content placerholder-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ENDS MAIN -->
                <footer>
                    <!-- bottom footer-->
                    <div class="footer-bottom">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span6 copyright">
                                    <p><b>Copyright © 2014 Luis Valencia - All Rights Reverved</b>
                                    </p>
                                </div>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--end bottom footer-->
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Check;

[Bootstrap 3 responsive not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156510/bootstrap-3-responsive-not-working-on-mobile)

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `viewport` meta tag.  Add this within your `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

What this does is essentially instructs the device that 'width' should be considered the device's width.  The device can then use that to compare against your media-queries and decide how to display the page.