# Bootstrap form alignment and sizing

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a simple control panel using Bootstrap and HTML5. I am having an issue where some of the elements in my form are not vertically aligning.

Here is a jsfiddle illustrating the problem along with the form html.

https://jsfiddle.net/srose/rqmu3uyr/

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="control-panel" name="control-panel" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <div id="statusSelector" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                  <label id="btnEnabled" class="btn btn-success active disabled">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Enabled
                                  </label>
                                  <label id="btnDisabled" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Disabled
                                  </label>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mode</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input name="RadioOptions" type="radio" value="view-only" checked="checked">View Only
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input name="RadioOptions" type="radio" value="Save-on-motion">Save on motion
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

You can see 'status' and 'mode' aren't aligned.

Does anyone know what the issue is here? Also, how would I get the panel to scale to fill the whole screen when viewed on a phone screen? Currently the buttons are very small when viewed on mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap add some css to `div` tag. In your first `from-group` you had 2 divs instead of one in the second `form-group`. You can resolve it by merging the 2 divs of the first `from-group`.

And `</div>` missing in first group, take care about it.

**First `from-group`**

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div id="statusSelector" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
```

**Second`from-group`**

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
```

**First `from-group` merged**

```
<div  id="statusSelector" class="col-sm-9 btn-group"  data-toggle="buttons">
```

**Live example here**:

https://jsfiddle.net/jvLhh6fq/

---

**Scale**

Now for the scale I recommand you this post:

[Responsive website zoomed out to full width on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156510/responsive-website-zoomed-out-to-full-width-on-mobile)