# Website displaying strangley on mobile when using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating an admin area using Bootstrap. When I resize my screen via dragging it and making it smaller, the website looks exactly how I would expect:

[image]

However when I view it on mobile it zooms out and looks like it tries to show the whole screen. Like below

[image]

Has anyone experianced this issue before with Bootstrap? I'm thinking it could be a Javascript issue where it doesn't detect the size of the browser?

Comment: could you share the code for this page ?

Comment: Do you have a viewport meta tag in your header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive website zoomed out to full width on mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156510/responsive-website-zoomed-out-to-full-width-on-mobile)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the `<head>` section of your HTML document.

> This means that the browser will (probably) render the width of the
>   page at the width of its own screen.

— [Chris Coyer on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

You can [check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) for more information about the viewport meta tag and its usage.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to but had to wait 10 mins then completely forgot!

Answer (score -1):

please set this meta tag in  tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to stop the user from being able to scale/zoom when using mobile devices, as some people may not be able to see your site easily if they're restricted to a certain zoom level.