# Bootstrap responsive issue in phone or mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am testing out Bootstrap responsiveness navbar and I have a website.[edisystems.in](http://edisystems.in)

When I resize the browser on a desktop, it all works fine including the nav bar which become collapsible menu with a small icon on the top which I can click to see more menu buttons.

But when I tried it from a mobile browser (I tried it on chrome and internet browser on an Android), I didn't see the responsive design. I could only see very small version of desktop like website.

when i host it on my domain mobile responsive is not working. **edisystems.in**
but when i upload it on free domain it's working like charm. http://beeingparth.000webhostapp.com help me to solve this issue.

Comment: so it's not working before you uploaded it on cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved it. Go with your mobile to edisystems.co and you will get your mobile version of the site.

stackoverflow post [Responsive website zoomed out to full width on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156510/responsive-website-zoomed-out-to-full-width-on-mobile) by **ZimSystem**
This is cause from your meta tags

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

You have a strange html, with 2 heads. As the first one from edisystem.in are empty, you will not get the responsive layout.

So add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

to the following code

```
<head>
  <title>edisystems.in</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
```

The second page `edisystems.co` works because there you create a new html document with

```
<html>
   <head>
   ..... some code
   <meta name="viewport"...>
```

---

### Update

Check the screenshot, you will see it. You have 2 pages one inside the other. Each one have one header. Edisystem.co has no header meta tags while edisystem.in has metatag. 
[image]

Comment: actually edisystems.in is linked from edisystems.com so edisystems.in directley takes all codes, i have not writen any code at edisystems.in. what to do if i want to use edisystems.in as Mobile -Friendly

Comment: @ParthPatel I update my answer so you understand what I mean